# C++ Pointers and reference and functions

Tags: c++, reference

I dont understand how this code works can you please explain it  to me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun (int &x, int &y) {
    if (y<=0)
        return x;
    x=x+2;
    cout<<x<<y<<endl;
    return x*y;
}

int main () {
    int x=5, y=-1;
    cout <<fun(x,y)<<endl;
    fun(y,x);
    fun(x,y);
    fun(y,x);
    cout <<fun(x,y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the correct answers are

```
5
15
71
37
93 
27
```

Comment: refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm and i hope you know c++

Comment: What are your concrete problems?

Comment: you sent a python link. And no i do not know C++ thats why Im asking the question. lol   what do these functions return

Comment: how do they return those numbers can you explain the process. What are the intermediate x and y values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function call `cout << fun(x,y) << endl;` passes x as 5 and y as -1.  Because y is less than 0 the function simply returns x to cout, so it prints 5.

The next function call `fun(y,x)` which still passes -1 and 5, however this time the values are passed in reverse so within the function x is -1 and y is 5.  Because y is 5 the if statement is false and x is assigned -1 + 2, or 1.  Then x as 1 and y as 5 are printed and the multiplication of the two is returned, however nothing is done with the multiplied value.

The third function call passes x and y, but in the previous function call x (as y) was changed to 1.  Because the value was passed in as a reference of y, it is now 1.  So, x is assinged 5 + 2 and x and y are printed as 71.

The fourth function call passes x and y again in reverse.  So, recall that x was changed to 7 and y is 1.  But the values are in reverse so in our function x is 1 and y is 7.  So again x is assigned the value of 1 + 2 and these are printed as 3 and 7.

Finally, the last function call passes x and y, but remember that x (as y) was changed to 3.  So now x is 7 and y is 3.  Once more x is assigned 7 + 2, and x and y are printed as 93.  Since the function was called from a cout statement the multiplication of 9 and 3 is also printed as 27.

Comment: Thank you so much I thought the answer was 71 not 7 1